# Setting exFAT Drive to Read Only in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I've been trying various ways of trying to get powershell to set an exFAT drive (USB or SD Card) to be read only based on a user input. The volume label is blank/empty.

Ive read through the [Set-Partition cmdlet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848710(v=wps.630).aspx) and that didn't work, found an example on here which also didn't work...

Here is what I have at the moment

```
$driveLetter = Read-Host "Enter drive letter (e.g. D) to make read-only"
$drive = Get-PSDrive -Name $driveLetter.TrimEnd(":")
#$result = Set-Partition -DriveLetter $drive -IsReadOnly $True
#$result = Set-Volume -DriveLetter $drive.Name -IsReadOnly $true -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#$result = & fsutil volume setreadonly $driveLetter 1 2> $null
$result = get-disk -Number (Get-Partition -DriveLetter $drive).disknumber | Set-Disk -IsReadOnly $true

if ($result) {
    Write-Output "Read-only attribute successfully set"
} else {
    Write-Output "Read-only attribute failed to set for some reason"
}
pause
```

which always fails with an error

```
    Set-Partition : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'DriveLetter'. Cannot convert the "F" value of
type "System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo" to type "System.Char".
At C:\Scripts\ReadOnly.ps1:3 char:38
+ $result = Set-Partition -DriveLetter $drive -IsReadOnly $True

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Partition], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-Partition
```

It looks to me like a type error with the user entered data for the drive but I can't for the life of me seem to find a way how to fix it - mind has gone numb! Any help and pointers/fixes would be greatfully appreciated :)

Comment: Does it work using `$drive.Name` (as shown on an earlier line in the question)?

Comment: Perhaps even cast to `Char`: `([char]$drive.Name)` ?

Comment: Unfortunately none of the options/trials worked that were then commented out so I could try them again using slightly different versions later and knew what I had/hadn't tried

Comment: Try taking the first **character** of the driveletter the user typed in: `$result = Set-Partition -DriveLetter $driveLetter[0] -IsReadOnly $True`. That way you are sure to use a **char**, not a string since `$driveLetter[0].GetType().Name` --> `Char`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense though I managed to eventually get it working after numerous disk and volume errors using the solution that I have now posted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix it, I gave up this method and shifted over to using Diskpart, there may be a better way but it kept struggling with errors initially to find the drive or volume - so this was my solution:

```
$drive = Read-Host "Enter drive letter (e.g. D) to make read-only"
# truncate user entry to first character
$driveLetter = $drive.Name.Substring(0, 1)

$partition = Get-Partition -DriveLetter $driveLetter
$diskNumber = $partition.DiskNumber

$diskpartScript = @"
select disk $diskNumber
attributes disk set readonly
attributes disk
"@

$diskpartOutput = $diskpartScript | diskpart
if ($diskpartOutput -match "Current Read-only State : Yes") {
    Write-Output "`nSuccess! Drive is now write-protected"
    } else {
        Write-Output "`nWrite protect failed for some reason"
    }
}
```

This obviously requires admin priviledges which can be checked using these lines beforehand

```
$isAdmin = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)

if (!$isAdmin) {
    Write-Host "This script requires admin privileges. Please run it as an administrator."
    pause
    Exit 1
}
```

It does end up showing more data on screen than I'd like, but if I use the Output-Null on diskpart then the if statement fails... It works so I'm leaving it at that! Also changed the drive acquisition to look for a particular filename too using these lines in place of the user inputted $drive acquisition and subsequent truncation.

```
$drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where-Object {$_.Free -gt 0 -and $_.Name -ne "C"}
$found = $false
foreach ($drive in $drives) {
    $file = Join-Path -Path $drive.Root -ChildPath "Test.txt"
    if (Test-Path $file) {
        $driveLetter = $drive.Name.Substring(0, 1)
        Write-Output "`nTest.txt found on $driveLetter"
        $found = $true
```